# best way to switch between using implementations of interface in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a WPF project using the MVVM pattern.  I have an interface that for this purpose I'll call **IMyData** which I currently have 2 implementations of ***myDataImplA*** & ***myDatImplB***.  I want my ViewModel to be able to switch between using these 2 implementations on the fly.  Currently I am passing in both implementations of the interface into the ViewModel's constructor and have Boolean property in which a ToogleButton in the View is bound to determine which one to use.  I feel like there is probably a better way to do this and passing in both implementations of **IMyData** just feel wrong.  Also if I end up having a 3rd implementation of **IMyData** my current method of using a Boolean to determine the implementation of **IMyData** to use won't work.

The interface could be updated on the fly from the view, but that would break MVVM as I think that would require extra code-behind in my View.I am looking for a more scalable solution which fits within MVVM.

Comment: Why don't you use property injection instead of constructor injection? Then you can set the property to any implementation of the interface at any time.

Comment: Can I do property injection with the binding of a UI control in the View?  Please post a short example or some pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assumption this is wrong is, IMO, accurate.  The whole reason to implement the `IMyData` should be to avoid this behavior altogether.

I'm not sure how you have the project setup but just to help you along solving this logic consider the ViewModel just an endpoint where business logic does not live.  Your ViewModel should communicate to a DAL (Data Access Layer), in which case, will pump out Model information that it updates against.

Since you're using an interface the DAL should provide that interface instantiated to the ViewModel.  Implement a command (`ICommand`) in the ViewModel that dictates state only, such as an enum.  Tell the DAL which state you want.  When the DAL updates your ViewModel should be listening and react to it.  At this point the ViewModel then updates the `IMyData` property, which should be notifying listeners, and the View will automatically change (If everything is wired up correctly.).

This probably sounds confusing so I'll try to simplify a different way.

Keep the references in a one way direction at all costs.

View -> ViewModel -> DAL  (DAL is considered Model in MVVM, which in your case pumps out IMyData).

Let the View bind to a command in ViewModel stating if it wants StateN for example.

ViewModel then tells DAL to switch to StateN or automatically looks for StateN models.

DAL then changes the IMyData type to the type that works in StateN.

The ViewModel is listening to DAL for changes and when the DAL says StateNChanged the ViewModel updates the IMyData property from the DAL, which fires off a notification.

The View, bound to the ViewModel, then updates based on the new data.

If this doesn't make sense, post most of the code and I'll make the modifications and show it.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want to do, but I didn't know I could use a Command to achieve it.

Comment: Let me see if I can update the answer with an example ICommand in the ViewModel and hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Michael an example would be much appreciated!

Comment: I put together an entire project example just for you titled WPF_ICommand_Example and it's based on this question from the ground up.  You can pick it apart and ask as many question as you want but I'd like to email it to you.  My email is michael_puckett_ii@hotmail.com  Anyone else interested in this question for an answer may request it also.  If needed I'll throw it up on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The view model shouldn't have any dependency upon any implementation of the `IMyData` interface. It should only have a dependency upon the interface itself.

Since you want to be able to switch the implementation dynamically at runtime, you could add a property to the view model that provides a default and interchangeable implementation:

```
public IMyData CurrentImplementation { get; set; } = new myDataImplA();
```

The view, or any other component, can then switch implemenation as requrired by simply setting this property.

Comment: I agree with this, but this is the sort of solution that I was referring to at the end of my post: **_"The interface could be updated on the fly from the view, but that would break MVVM as I think that would require extra code-behind in my View."_**  Your example doesn't show demonstrate how to do it within the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Are you saying that binding to or setting a property of a view model breaks the MVVM pattern...? What kind of implementation are you referring to here? It's fine for the view to inject the view model. Please clarify your issue.

Comment: I agree that it is fine to do, but I work in a strict environment where I'm not supposed to be putting much of anything in the View's code-behind.  Can I do the injection with a binding?

Comment: Yes, of course. It's just a property that you can bind to.